# Get date column from numpy loadtxt()

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a text file which contains following table.

```
Day  Month Year Avg Power
01     01  2000 30 
02     01  2000 41
04     01  2000 55
05     01  2000 78
06     01  2000 134
07     01  2000 42
```

I want to load the Day,month and year columns into single datetime value. To do that followed following steps. But the code doesn't work what I expect.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import datetime

def date_converter(x,y,z):
    date = "{},{},{}".format(x,y,z)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date,r"%d,%m,%Y")

data3 = loadtxt('complex_data_file.txt',dtype=int, usecols=(0,1,2,4),
                converters={(0,1,2):date_converter,3:int})
```

What I have to do to achieve my requirement?

Comment: A `converter` converts one string (column) into one value.  It can't consolidate several columns (or split one).  You'll need to do the conversion after loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use Pandas module for this task:

```
In [228]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=[0,1,2,4], parse_dates={'Date':[2,1,0]})

In [229]: df
Out[229]:
        Date  Avg Power
0 2000-01-01         30
1 2000-01-02         41
2 2000-01-04         55
3 2000-01-05         78
4 2000-01-06        134
5 2000-01-07         42

In [230]: df.dtypes
Out[230]:
Date         datetime64[ns]
Avg Power             int64
dtype: object
```

it's also very easy to convert it to a Numpy array:

```
In [231]: df.values
Out[231]:
array([[Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), 30],
       [Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'), 41],
       [Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00'), 55],
       [Timestamp('2000-01-05 00:00:00'), 78],
       [Timestamp('2000-01-06 00:00:00'), 134],
       [Timestamp('2000-01-07 00:00:00'), 42]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the official [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), converters works as follows.

> converters : dict, optional
>   A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Default: None.

So, converters cannot handle several columns. You'll need to do the conversion after loading. You can do something like this.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import datetime

def date_converter(x,y,z):
    date = "{},{},{}".format(x,y,z)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date,r"%d,%m,%Y")

data3 = loadtxt('file.txt',dtype=int, usecols=(0,1,2,3))
converted_data3 = [[date_converter(row[0], row[1], row[2]), row[3]] for row in data3]
for item in converted_data3:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), 30]
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 0), 41]
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 4, 0, 0), 55]
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 78]
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 6, 0, 0), 134]
[datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 7, 0, 0), 42]
```